# Setting up firebase (custom) dynamic links for email verification

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

So I am currently struggling with 3 aspects related to email verification and setting it up in a way where when user clicks link in email he / she goes to app where I can then check if email was verified and show new view, aka dynamic linking?

**1)** I assume correct way to achieve this is by using [User.sendEmailVerification(completion)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/User#/c:objc(cs)FIRUser(im)sendEmailVerificationWithActionCodeSettings:completion:) ? I am struggling with setting up the completion step and would appreciate if someone could guide me through the process, also I am not 100% sure that this configures the deeplink, I might've miss-understood it.

---

**2)** If my assumption above is wrong, do I need to set up a dynamic link in firebase and then in my email templates section set it as url instead of default one i.e. `myApp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth etc...` If I do it this way I can retrieve token for verifying user, do I need to perform a call in app to post it to firebase somehow once I have it?

---

**3)** If I do need to use approach no.2, is there a way to use my own domain for dynamic links? i.e. I can set up small landing page with `app-associate` file for iOS and equivalent for Android, will this be enough? Do I miss out on any things like analytics here? Would you recommend for or against using custom domain for dynamic links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/passing-state-in-email-actions is the primary guide for this.

1. `user.sendEmailVerification(withActionCodeSettings:actionCodeSettings`) - see the snippet in the doc above.
2. You need to support Dynamic Links, that is how the user is returned to your app.
3. Your own domain is not necessary.